# Examples of fusenes that are not polyhexes

Tags: oeis, polyomino

OEIS sequence [A108070](https://oeis.org/A108070) describes

> Number of fusenes with n hexagons.

OEIS sequence [A000228](https://oeis.org/A000228) describes

> Number of hexagonal polyominoes with n cells.

These sequences first disagree at $A108070(7) = 339 \neq 333 = A000228(7)$.

Given the definitions of [fusenes](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Fusene.html) and of [polyhexes](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Polyhex.html), it appears that all polyhexes are fusenes.

---

What are the six $7$-fusenses that are not $7$-polyhexes?

Comment: I figured it out. There are two $7$-polyhexes that are not $7$-fusenses, and eight $7$-fusenses that are not $7$-polyhexes. Basically, a ring of six hexagons that does not meet, but "spirals up" like a helix is a valid fusense but not a valid polyhex. A polyhex with a hole in it is not a valid fusense.